# No route found for "GET /lucky/number"

Tags: symfony, netbeans, routes

I've already looked at other posts here,  none of their solutions worked.
Tried prefixing "<\?php" to the file,
Tried change clearing the cache.
None have worked.

Working on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.
Running within the NetBeans IDE

LuckyNumberController.php  is below:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Controller/LuckyController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LuckyController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/lucky/number",name="lucky")
 */
 public function numberAction()
 {
    $number = rand(0, 100);

    return new Response(
        '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
    );
  }
}
```

Routing.yml below:

```
app:
    resource: @AppBundle/Controller/
    type:     annotation

homepage:
    path: /
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Template:template
        template:    'default/homepage.html.twig'

lucky:
    path: /lucky/number
    controller: App\Controller\LuckyController::numberAction
```

Comment: Don't mix annotations with explicit routes.  Remove the lucky entry from the routing file.  bin/console debug:router will tell you if it worked.

Comment: It looks like the route that you created here is `/lucky/number/lucky/number` because of the double entry. If you want `/lucky` to be automatically applied to all actions in the `LuckyController` then leave it in `Routing.yml` and remove it from the controller. Else just remove it from `Routing.yml`.

Comment: I tried your suggestions, same result.

Comment: I think I've had it with symfony,   I would have already written the app by now in plain PHP.   Nice looking URL's aren't even on the projects requirements list.

Answer (score 1):

Actually both your declarations might be wrong.

### Annotation

In your controller you're using

`use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;`

and according to [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/routing.html), it seems to be correct for Symfony <=3.3 but wrong for Symfony >=3.4 which should be

`use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;`.

### Yaml

In your yaml file you're specifying

`controller: App\Controller\LuckyController::numberAction`

while actually your Controller's namespace is `AppBundle\Controller;` so your declaration should be

`controller: AppBundle\Controller\LuckyController::numberAction`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however I've decided not too use Symfony because of its inconsistencies with the customers requirements.  It was my fault for just trying to pick up a framework without researching it more thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need annotations routing and yml routing. You have to pick just one. I preferred yml version

Delete

```
...
/**
 * @Route("/lucky/number",name="lucky")
 */
...
```

or you can delete this one

```
...
lucky:
    path: /lucky/number
    controller: App\Controller\LuckyController::numberAction
...
```

After that, it will work.

## EDIT1:

If you are using Symfony 4 I recommended use yaml version (second one) because this one comes with (Symfony)

## EDIT2:

I mean don't be confuse when you are creating new route.

Comment: You don't have to pick one. You can use them in conjunction. This can be useful if you need to change a static part of your route as it is stored in one place and requires one change. But you do need to understand not to duplicate the static part in both files.

Comment: The reason there are two, is because having just one didn't work either.  Trying to delete either one does not work.  Is there a good book on this somewhere?

Comment: @hcoat Actually I mean don't be confuse when you are typing new route/path

Comment: @kiwicomb123 In "Mastering Symfony" book (Sohail Salehi, Packt Publishing, 2016, 978-1-78439-031-0) page 25, showing how can you using routing with annotation